# Can anyone help me to make a Table of content like the one in the picture. Thanks

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Table of content problem]

Can anyone help me to make a Table of content like the one in the picture. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using? Do you already use any packages to format the table of contents?

Comment: Please be more specific about which parts of the displayed table of contents you wish to replicate? E.g., is it the use of sans-serif fonts for chapter- and section-level entries and the use of a serif font for subsection-level entries? Is it the use of a serif font for the entries in the frontmatter? Is it the particular pattern of identations? Is it the underlining of chapter-level entries? Are there any other formatting objectives I missed? Do you wish to achieve all of the above? Please be specific. Please also indicate which fonts and font sizes you wish to employ.

Comment: Thanks all. I did it for my favourite.